# Bash seems to convert LF into LFCR

Tags: bash, separator, carriage-return, linefeed

It seems that Bash converts LF to LFCR. Indeed, here is an example bellow that describes that:

```
text=$(echo -e "foo\nbar\ntir")
```

When setting IFS to the LF end of line:

`IFS=$(echo -e "\n")`

the `\n` in the string `text` is not interpreted such as bellow:

```
for w in $text ; do echo ${w}';' ; done
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
tir;
```

Here the character ";" used as a marker shows that `$text` contains only one element and so `\n` is not interpreted although it was set as the IFS.

But now, while setting IFS to the LFCR end of line:

`IFS=$(echo -e "\n\r")`

the output of the previous command turns into:

```
foo;
bar;
tir;
```

The marker ";" shows that `$text` contains three elements and thereby `\n` in `$text` has been interpreted as a `\n\r` (LFCR) set as the IFS.

So, why does Bash seems convert LF to LFCR? If it does not, what is the underlying explanation please?

Comment: You aren't trying to avoid the proper use of an array, are you? `text=(foo bar tir); for w in "${text[@]}"; do echo "$w;"; done`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$IFS` is actually being set to an empty string.

```
$ IFS=$(echo -e "\n")
$ echo "[$IFS]"
[]
```

When `$(...)` captures output it removes trailing newlines. You can set `$IFS` to a newline by using `$'...'`, shell syntax that interprets escape sequences while avoiding the trimming problem.

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ echo "[$IFS]"
[
]
$ text=$'foo\nbar\nbaz\n'
$ printf '%s;\n' $text
foo;
bar;
baz;
```